# How to associate Azure deployments to the users?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops

I am working on deploying resources in to Azure using ARM Templates. I am one of five in my team. After deploying any resource into Azure portal, we need to know which user has deployed specific resource deployment into Azure including time. Because the deployment process has done randomly into Azure by the users.

How to find the details of specific user after deployment?

Comment: define `find the details of specific user`

Answer (score 1):

No way can associate the Azure deployments to the users smoothly. Seems you want to check the deployment logs.

In VSTS you can create a notification subscription for the deployments, thus you will receive the notifications once a deployment is triggered and you can check the deploy logs...

Another workaround is checking the Activity Logs in Azure. Please see [View activity logs to audit actions on resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit) for details. You can also try the REST API:[Activity Logs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs/list)

You can also view the operations for a deployment through the Azure portal. Please see[View deployment operations with Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-operations) for details.